# Whether VS2015 can build project target for Windows Phone 10 and Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-phone-8, windows-10

#### Question

Whether Visual Studio 2015 support building targets both for windows phone 8.1 and windows phone 10?

#### Description

I have a project which needs support both Windows Phone 10 and Windows phone 8.1,
I initially created a windows universal project (library) for Windows Phone 10, after finishing my program, I need build for Windows Phone 8.1, but I found the project cannot be built for Windows Phone 8.1 via `project Property` -> `General` -> `Target Platform` as it is disabled.

#### More details,

I have installed windows sdk10, and sdk8.1.
The project is built with `VC++/Windows/Universal/Runtime Component` Template

Comment: Do you have the "Windows Phone 8.1 Tools" options installed in Visual Studio? You must explicitly select them during Setup, if not you need to add them by using the "Programs and Features" control panel. Installing the WP8.1 SDK is not enough to enable Visual Studio support.

Comment: @Dai, thanks for your suggestion. I just tried to `repair` my VS2015, and ensure `windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.0/8.1 Tools` get checked and restart computer. It doesn't work for me. I still cannot build for Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

You probably selected wrong project type in Visual Studio Wizard - Windows Universal Platform introduced in Windows 10 is not backward compatible, so you won't be able to retarget it to Win8.1
[image: Windows 10 Universal Class Library]

In order to support both Windows 8.1 and Win10 Universal you need to create a project for Universal Windows 8.1:
[image: Windows 8.1 Universal Class Library]
With it you will be able to support both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 Universal

Comment: Agree. We can only build runtime component for win8.1 and win10 in separate projects in same solution, but we cannot build it in same project. VC++/Windows/Universal/Runtime Component project template is only for win10.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support Windows 10 and Windows Phone 8.1 as well you can create a project for each and then share code via a PCL or Shared Project.  The majority of your code should be able to be shared in order to limit code redundancy.  Certainly, there will be some pieces that won't carry over, and these pieces would go in their specific project folders instead of shared.